# SwiftUI: How to display the second Sheet when first sheet is closed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make a side menu with `.fullScreenCover`, when a user is logged in and press MyGarage button. the `.fullScreenCover` will dismiss and the main view will navigate to MyGarage View. But if user is not logged in the `.fullScreenCover` will dismiss and a loginView with `.fullScreenCover` will appear. My problem is, the `.fullScreenCover` will not work if I put 2 same `.fullScreenCover` inside the main view. Is there any way to solve this? I'm sorry it's a little bit difficult for me to explain.

Here's the code

SideMenuView

```
struct SideMenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var showMyGarage: Bool
    @Binding var showSignIn: Bool
    var user = 0 //If user is 1, it is logged in
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    if user == 1 {
                        self.showMyGarage = true
                    }else{
                        self.showSignIn = true
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("My Garage")
                })
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    HStack(spacing: 20){
                                        Button(action: {
                                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                        }, label: {
                                            Text("X")
                                        })
                                        Text("Main Menu")
                                    }
                )
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

MainView

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var showSideMenu = false
    @State private var showMyGarage = false
    @State var showSignIn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Text("Home")
            
            NavigationLink(destination: MyGarageView(showMyGarage: $showMyGarage), isActive: $showMyGarage){
                EmptyView()
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showSideMenu.toggle()
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Menu")
                                })
            )
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSideMenu, content: {
            SideMenuView(showMyGarage: $showMyGarage, showSignIn: $showSignIn)
        })
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSignIn, content: {
            SignInView()
        })

    }
}

struct MyGarageView: View {
    @Binding var showMyGarage: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("MyGarage")
    }
}

struct SignInView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sign In")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to attach them to different views, like

```
var body: some View {
    VStack{

        Text("Home")
          .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSideMenu, content: {
             SideMenuView(showMyGarage: $showMyGarage, showSignIn: $showSignIn)
          })
        
        NavigationLink(destination: MyGarageView(showMyGarage: $showMyGarage), isActive: $showMyGarage){
            EmptyView()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSignIn, content: {
           SignInView()
        })
    }
    .navigationBarItems(leading:
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showSideMenu.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Menu")
                            })
        )
}
```